# Aspect does not trigger around repositories in my application

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to trigger my aspect for classes annotated with repositories and belonging to my packages, for example this one:

```java
//com.foo.myapp.bar.repositories.dao
@Repository
public class MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>{
```

My classes are jpa repositories created like this:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.foo.myapp.bar.repositories.first.dao"}
```

)
public class DbConfig {

My aspect is the following but only activates if I leave the repository() pointcut, but if I also specify application packages it doesn't work:

```java
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)")
private void repositoryInvocation() {
    // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
}

@Pointcut("within(com.foo.myapp..*)")
public void applicationPackage() {
    // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
}

@Around("repositoryInvocation() && applicationPackage()") //this && doesn't work, I have to remove the second one
public Object aspectTriggers(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    return result;
}
```

What am I missing?

**edit:**

I think I got it: problem is that the implementation of the repository does not belong to my application package, but to spring's SimpleJPARepository. It's like the aspect is only working on the implementation, totally ignoring the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not want

```java
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)")
```

but rather

```java
@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)")
```

Be careful with your pointcut syntax, the two are **not the same**:

- `within()` describes a package or class name you want to scope/limit your pointcut to.
- `@within()` looks for a type (class) with the given annotation.

You want the latter, not the former.

---

**Edit:** On a second thought, actually I see no obvious reason why the first version should not work, even though it is a bit more complicated than the second.

But you said that you had problems with the second pointcut anyway. Are you 100% sure that your repository class really is in a `com.foo.myapp` (sub) package? No typo in either the package name or the pointcut? Actually, without trying and only looking at it, it should work otherwise.

Comment: Strangely enough if I put the full package (com.foo.myapp.bar.repositories.dao) it works. Maybe there's some mistake in the second pointcut?

Comment: No, `within(com.foo.myapp..*)` covers all sub-packages. You must have made a mistake, such as a typo or just `.*` instead of `..*` at the end.

Comment: It is correct and it seems it works only if I specify the type. Maybe I have an hint: the @Repository implementation is a spring proxy, I don't have the actual class inside of that package. Could it be?

Comment: I also corrected the question as my setup is a bit more complicated...maybe it's that @enableJPARepositories?

Comment: I am not a Spring user, just an AOP expert. If you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub or so, I can take a look. It is always much easier if I can reproduce the problem.